# Camera saying busy and won't take pictures

Tags: canon, dslr

I am using a Canon-D1200 with 18-55 lens and some time after clicking it says Busy and I'm not able to take another picture for some time. Can anyone please tell me what the solution is for this, and why it's happening?

as commented, I am adding more detail.

**How long was the exposure time for the photo you took?** -  I tried with changing exposures time as well

**Do you have Long Exposure Noise Reduction enable?** - No

**What exposure mode are you using?** - I tried with many combinations

**What aperture, shutter time, and ISO?**  - I tried with many combinations but the same issue happened after some click

**What kind of environment? :** Normal room temperature

Comment: We'll need a little more information than you have provided to answer your question. How long was the exposure time for the photo you took? Do you have *Long Exposure Noise Reduction* enable? What exposure mode are you using? What aperture, shutter time, and ISO? What kind of environment? Very hot? Very cold? Normal room temperature?

Comment: I thought I commented last night but try with a different memory card (SD card in your camera I think). If you don't have a spare try cleaning the contacts on the card itself and reformatting it in the camera. "Busy" can mean that it's writing to the card, and is often seen after taking a burst of photos faster than they can be written.

Comment: Thanks, Michael and Chris. I think that issue with my memory card, let me change and  check. but I notice that it happens after some time.

Comment: Are you burst shooting? (i.e., holding down the shutter button to take more pictures).

Comment: @inkista I m not doing burst shooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canon T5, also known as 1200D (not D1200), has a [maximum burst rate of ~3 fps, for a maximum of 6 RAW files (or 69 JPEG's).](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/canon-t5/canon-t5A.HTM) In a test by [Digital Camera Review](http://www.digitalcamerareview.com/camerareview/canon-rebel-t5i-review/2/), the rate and maximum number of files achieved were considerably less.

This means that the camera can take only so many pictures before two issues get in the way:

1. The sensor and other electronics heat up, particularly for longer exposures.
2. High-speed memory, which buffers the image file before moving to the flash memory card, is overrun.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are getting a good SD card at least class 8 or so?
Because slow SD cards can lead to bottlenecking, and it's normally why it takes long for the image to process or save.

Comment: I used class 4 SD card so might be that's the issue.!! hw can i check the better card for my cam

Comment: You mean purchase a better card?
I don't understand what you mean by 'check'

Comment: mean how can i purchase a better card ? How can i check is this card is good or not?

Comment: Very late reply, sorry.
Since you have a class 4 your first option is just to go out and buy a class 10 because that's what most modern DSLR requires.
Especially in burst shoot or long exposure.

Look for UHS-1 and above or Class 8 and above.
https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/